# Malloc is throwing an error for pointer being freed

Tags: c, memory, struct, malloc, calloc

so I have a function that creates a flexible array type and all paths use calloc to define the size of the array. However when I try to destroy the struct, it says that the memory was not allocated.

```
typedef struct {
    int size;
    void *items;
} Array;

typedef enum {
    CHAR,
    INT,
    FLOAT,
    DOUBLE
} datatype;

Array *create_array(int initial_size, datatype type)
{
    Array *arr = malloc(sizeof(Array));

    arr->size = initial_size;

    switch (type) {
        case CHAR:
            arr->items = (char *) calloc(5, sizeof(char));
            break;
        case INT:
            arr->items = (int *) calloc(arr->size, sizeof(int));
            break;
        case FLOAT:
            arr->items = (float *) calloc(arr->size, sizeof(float));
            break;
        case DOUBLE:
            arr->items = (double *) calloc(arr->size, sizeof(double));
            break;
        default:
            exit(1); // will handle later on
            break;
    }
    return arr;
}

void destroy_array(Array *arr)
{
    free(arr->items); // this is the line that throws the error
    free(arr);
}
```

The exact error is:

*flexibleArray(63110,0x10c3c6600) malloc: *** error for object 0x600000c21120: pointer being freed was not allocated
flexibleArray(63110,0x10c3c6600) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug*

I just don't understand why memory I'm allocating with calloc does not require to be freed.

Thanks for anyone's input!

**Main Loop**

There is just a lot of random code in there that I am using to test out changing the size of the array. I don't think it would affect the outcome of the destroy function.

```
    int main() {
        Array *newArr = create_array(5, INT);
        int *val;
        int w = 20;
        val = &w;

        printf("%s\n", typename(w));

        ((int *)newArr->items)[0] = *val;
        ((int *)newArr->items)[1] = 35;
        ((int *)newArr->items)[2] = 20;
        ((int *)newArr->items)[3] = 351;
        ((int *)newArr->items)[4] = 315;

        for(int i = 0; i < newArr->size; i++) {
            printf("%d\n", ((int *)newArr->items)[i]);
        }

        realloc(newArr->items, 10);

        ((int *)newArr->items)[5] = 50;
        for(int i = 0; i < newArr->size; i++) {
            printf("%d\n", ((int *)newArr->items)[i]);
        }

        destroy_array(newArr);
    }
```

Comment: Unrelated: The `CHAR` case looks very wrong. Why is it allocating memory for 5 `char` instead of `arr->size` `char`? You also do not need to cast the `void*` you get from `calloc` to `int*` etc. It's especially pointless in this case since `arr->items` itself is a `void*`.

Comment: `realloc` returns a pointer for a reason.

Comment: `realloc(newArr->items, 10);` <- this - don't ignore the return value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently ignore the return value from `realloc`. If it needs to relocate the allocated data, you get undefined behavior.

Another problem is that you allocate room for `10` bytes, not `10` `int`.

Fix:

```
// allocate space for 10 `int`:
void* np = realloc(newArr->items, 10 * sizeof(int));

if(np) {
    // realloc success
    newArr->items = np;
} else {
    // realloc failure
    destroy_array(newArr);
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Retired Ninja and Ted Lyngmo!

Didn't see the * on the realloc documentation to see it returned a pointer to the new object. Using:

```
...

newArr->items = realloc(newArr->items, 10);
...
```

removed the error.

Thank you for the assistance!

Side note to another comment from Ted Lyngmo it was something was with generics I was playing around with. It was declared just did not put it in here...

Comment: That's only part of the problem

Comment: I am sure its riddled with all sorts of problems and things I'm not doing correctly. Slowly learning C there is a lot to it.

Comment: I'm assuming off your previous comment on the realloc I should use a size_t value (like sizeof(int)) instead of a normal int value.